# Why "Required kernel recording resources are in use by another document" error is thrown when I try to run Executable in Instruments-> Leaks?

Tags: ios, xcode, memory-leaks, instruments

I am trying to see the memory leaks of an app running over simulator but I am getting this error
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i6X3t.png)

I tried to test the memory leak on my app screen (app is running over simulator).

Also I am unable to get any of the proper valid documentation follow and find out the leak

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you’re trying to profile the Simulator app itself, rather than your app. The recommended way to profile an app using Simulator is to select the running simulated device from the left side of the target picker menu, then select your app from the right side. That will launch your process in the context of the simulator and profile only your process rather than attempting to profile the Simulator app itself. (Note that performance on the Simulator will not match performance on a real device so it’s recommended to do profiling on a physical device if possible)

The actual error message you’re seeing here is a bit unclear but what it’s trying to say is that security protections on macOS only allow in-development apps (technically, ones with the `get-task-allow` entitlement) to be profiled using certain instruments. Since the Simulator app is not an in-development app and is not signed with that entitlement, you won’t be able to profile it.